# ASP.NET Entity Model Physical Path

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm having trouble with my ASP.NET application.  Basically I've got it hooked up to an entity model representing a MySql database.  I've launched applications before using this same database, and they deploy just fine, however when I run this application I'm getting the following error:

---

**FIXED THIS ERROR**

---

*Now I'm receiving this error:*

Exception Details: System.Data.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

```
[MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.]
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) +2490148
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) +170
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) +8517824
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String paths) +271
   System.Data.Common.Utils.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0() +19
   System.Data.Common.Utils.Result.GetValue() +100
   System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg) +181
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections) +292
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection() +29
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor) +205
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName) +27
   AgentActivity.shoretelEntities..ctor() in c:\Projects\NET\AgentActivity\AgentActivity\ShoretelServer.Designer.cs:34
   AgentActivity.ReturnFile.ReturnAgentActivity(String startDate, String endDate) in c:\Projects\NET\AgentActivity\AgentActivity\ReturnFile.aspx.cs:271
   AgentActivity.ReturnFile.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Projects\NET\AgentActivity\AgentActivity\ReturnFile.aspx.cs:44
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Any ideas?  I'm at a loss on this one, I don't even where to begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the MySQL connector has not been deployed.
Have you verified if the [MySQL connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) is available on your server?

Checkout this post: [Deploy MySQL data provider to Production](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,266282,268477#msg-268477)

Comment: Yea that fixed that problem, I thought I had been using this database on this particular server in my other app, but I only tested that connection on my local box in that app.  The connector is now installed, thanks.  However, now I'm throwing a "System.Data.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource." error.